# Question on Probability generating function

Tags: self-study, probability-generating-fn

For a discrete random variable $X$ with the PGF P(z). I have been given $Y = 2X$ and I need to compute the PGF, G(Z) of this new random variable.

We know that the probability generating function is $E(z^x)$.

We can see that:

$G(z) = E(z^Y) = E(z^{2X}) = E((z^2)^x) = P(z^2)$.

So, these steps are what I am getting but None of the options give is giving me a result closer to what I am getting. The four options are:

1. $P(\sqrt{s}) + P(\sqrt{-s})$
2. $P(\sqrt{s}) - P(\sqrt{-s})$
3. $\frac{P(\sqrt{s}) + P(\sqrt{-s})}{2}$
4. $\frac{P(\sqrt{s}) - P(\sqrt{-s})}{2}$

Someone please let me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Xi'an, Yes, I just did that. But I have a question, I have been on this platform for quite some time now and I have been also asking a lot of questions and doubts. Please tell me precisely how does this question qualifies for "self study" tag. Please don't tell me the definition of the the tag, I have already read that.  This is not the question from any textbook, I have also solved this problem and got the answer but my answer is not consistent with the options given in paper.

Comment: This question has been bothering me for a long time because usually i ask question in a similar pattern always and that pattern is "First I state the problem or doubt and I explain my approach or what i think and where exactly my doubt exits?" But only for few selected problem, I get this comment from some people like you that you should add "self study" tag for this problem and I cannot fathom why is that so? What am i doing in problem differently that any other problems that I usually post?

Comment: I think the tag wiki is rather clear on that point. Adding the `self-study`  tag tells others to adapt their answer in a more pedagogical way, to help the OP see behind the answer itself and catch the principles at work so that the next time s/he meets a similar problem s/he can solve it. It also avoids the forum being submitted to an avalanche of homework questions being dumped with no input whatsoever from the OPs, not even about the background or the level of the course.

Comment: Addendum:  Concerning this very [multiple choice] question, I see no issue with your resolution.

Comment: True/false and multiple choice questions are *automatically* "self-study" because they arise only in artificial learning situations.  That makes them harder for us to respond to because often the answer depends on the learning context, which is rarely revealed, and usually there are no opportunities for further discovery of the objective or background of the question.

Comment: In this case, why not work out the answers explicitly for the simplest possible variable?  Take $P(z) = (1+z)/2,$ the pgf for a standard Bernoulli variable $X$.  Which of the five answers (if any) gives the pgf of $2X$?